# Android: Sync multiple asynchronous network calls in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have my network layer written in such a way that all the calls are made asynchronously using the Retrofit's `call.enqueue()`. I cannot change this implementation for several reasons, one being - it is written in Java.

**Example:**

```
repository.fetchUserData(object : NetworkListener<UserResponse> {
    override fun onSuccess(response: NetworkListener<UserResponse>?) {
    //back on UI thread
        userLiveData.value = response?.data
    }

    override fun onFailure(error: String) {
    //back on UI thread
        errorLiveData.value = error
    }
})
```

I am faced with a challenge of making several such network calls in parallel and show the data only when all of these calls are finished.

Using some boolean flags and tracking each network call finish, seems like a fragile solution.

Is there a better/simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin, it will be simpler way using async and await. If you want to continue to use Java, then you will have to use RxJava and combine the obeservales using merge or zip.

Comment: I am using `Kotlin` and did some research on `async and await`. However it seemed too much to go that route now. Because I have nothing to call in `async` once I am back on the UI thread, it would just force me to create unnecessary suspend functions and try to keep them in sync.

Comment: You can use multiple couroutines with async and call the api . Use await to wait for response from each one of them  and then proceed further.